# $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(G,H),H) \simeq G$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, duality-theorems

Let $G,H$ be abelian groups. Under what conditions would the following holds true $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(G,H),H) \simeq G$?

For example, if $G$ is any abelian group and $H=\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ the isomorphism holds true. This is well-known as [The Pontryagin duality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality). Is there any counterexample?

Comment: There are many pairs $G,H$ with $\mathrm{Hom}(G,H)=0$.

Comment: I think you meant $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(G,H),H) \simeq G$, both in the title and the question body?

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right. I've edited.

Comment: The isomorphism you mention only exists for a *finite* abelian group $G$. If $G=\mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ is much bigger than $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @egreg In the link above, it's written that $\widehat{\Bbb T}=\Bbb Z$. I think it means $\widehat{\Bbb T}\simeq\Bbb Z$ as groups? Or just bijections between two sets?

Comment: @user $\hat{\mathbb{T}}$ is the group of *continuous* endomorphisms of $\mathbb{T}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a very hard question to answer.

Let's work in the more restrictive assumption that $G$ is finitely generated, so $G=\mathbb{Z}^n\oplus t(G)$, with $t(G)$ the torsion part of $G$. Then
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\Hom(G,H)\cong H^n\oplus\Hom(t(G),H)
$$
Note that $\Hom(t(G),H)$ is torsion of finite exponent. Then
$$
\Hom(\Hom(G,H),H)\cong
\Hom(H^n\oplus\Hom(t(G),H),H)\cong
\Hom(H^n,H)\oplus\Hom(\Hom(t(G),H),H)
$$
The second summand is torsion, so the rank only comes from the first summand, which is $\Hom(H,H)^n$.

In particular the rank of $\Hom(H,H)$ cannot be $>1$. It must be $1$ if $G$ is not torsion, which means that $\Hom(H,H)/K$ is torsion, where $K$ is the image of the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\Hom(H,H)$.

If $G$ is not torsionfree, then $H$ has to be not torsionfree as well.

Note that there is *no* group $H$ so that $\Hom(\Hom(G,H),H)\cong G$ for every abelian group $G$. The case you mention of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't work generally, but only for *finite* groups. I'll leave to you finding the reason. The Pontryagin dual of a group $G$ is $G^*=\Hom(G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ endowed with the topology induced by the product topology, where $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is identified with the circle. The the double dual is the group of *continuous* homomorphism $G^*\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and it is this “restricted” dual that's isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Assume that we forget all the topology and only focus on the abstract groups. If $G$ is any finitely generated abelian group, is it true that $ \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(G,\Bbb R/\Bbb Z),\Bbb R/\Bbb Z) \simeq G$, as groups? Or $ \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(G,\Bbb R/\Bbb Z),\Bbb R/\Bbb Z)= G$ as sets?

Comment: @user No. Only for finite $G$.

Comment: @user They use “Hom” to denote continuous homomorphisms. Otherwise, the statement fails horribly.

Comment: To ensure I understand your point correctly, $\Hom(\Hom(G,H),H)\cong G$ as topological groups when $G$ is any finitely generated abelian group and $H=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{T}, \mathbb{C}^\times$?

Comment: @user It is not true for $H=\mathbb{C}^\times$. What's true is that, if $G$ is a locally compact abelian group, then $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb{T}),\mathbb{T})\cong G$ as topological groups (with the “compact-open” topology on the dual, with $\mathrm{Hom}$ denoting continuous homomorphisms. Note that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{T}$ are topologically isomorphic.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the invalidity of the isomorphism when $H=\mathbb{C}^\times$?

Comment: @user Try for yourself. The continuous homomorphisms $\mathbb{C}^\times\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ don't form a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, do they? The paper mentions Lie groups for that case.

Comment: No, they don't. Because $\mathbb{C}^\times \simeq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{T}$ and $\widehat{\mathbb{T}} = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @user Yes, the continuous endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ also contain a copy of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see, because $\mathbb{R}$ is self-dual. In the second last comment, did you mean the isomorphism $\Hom(\Hom(G,\mathbb{C}^\times),\mathbb{C}^\times)\cong G$ can be validated with regard to Lie groups?

Comment: @user I didn't look much into the paper.

Comment: I see. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $G=\mathbf Z$, as $\;\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom(\mathbf Z,H)\simeq H$, it implies
$$\Hom(H,H)\simeq H$$
which is false in general. For instance, if $H=\mathbf Z^n$, it would mean that $\;\mathbf Z^{n^2}\simeq\mathbf Z^n$.